# Promises resolving out of order

Tags: 2013, 2016, angularjs, promises

**Environment**

- SharePoint 2016
- AngularJS 1.5.4

**Situation**

I have a query service that wraps REST calls retrieving data from SharePoint lists. This service works without issue in SP 2013, but it is somehow misbehaving in SP 2016.

Here is the meat of the function I'm calling in the query service.

```
var promise = $http({
  "headers": { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  "method": "GET",
  "params": {
    "$expand": "Employee",
    "$filter": "PID eq '" + codePid + "'",
    "$orderby": "",
    "$select": "Title,PID,Company,Employee/EMail,Employee/Title"
  },
  "url": _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + nameList + "')/items"
}).error(function (data, status) {
  if (data && data.hasOwnProperty("code")) {
    console.error("Error " + data.error.code + " - " + data.error.message.value);
  } else {
    console.error("Error:\t", status);
  }
}).then(function extractResponseArray(response) {
  return response.data.d.results;
});
return promise;
```

Here is the code calling that function.

```
function getDataToDelete(codePid) {
  var promises = {};
  for (var nameList in infoLists) {
    promises[nameList] = qryService.getData(nameList, codePid);
  }
  return $q.all(promises);
}
function deleteData(responses) {
  var dataCoalesced = [];
  for (var nameList in responses) {
    dataCoalesced = dataCoalesced.concat(
      responses[nameList].map(
        function getDeletePromise(dataToDelete) {
          return qryService.deleteData(nameList, dataToDelete);
        }
      )
    );
  }
  return $q.all(dataCoalesced);
}
promptForDeletion(codePid)
  .then(getDataToDelete)
  .then(deleteData);
```

**Issue**

So, here's the problem. The function calls `promptForDeletion` and calls `getDataToDelete` appropriately. In SP 2013, it calls `extractResponseArray` before it calls `deleteData` as expected. However, in the SP 2016 environment, it calls `deleteData` before it calls `extractResponseArray` and the `responses` variable passed to `deleteData` is a promise, not the object expected (either with the promise members or the promise resolutions).

Why are the `.then` functions getting called out of order?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this issue was a little outside the code that was posted, in the `promptForDeletion` function. This function presented a prompt confirming deletion and, after confirming deletion, could present a second. The function was not returning the `Promise` correctly in one of those cases and that was affecting the behavior of the functions to follow.